# What does RV 1.156.5 literally mean?

Tags: vedas, vishnu, translation-request, indra

[RV 1.156.5](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv01156.htm)

> आ यो विवाय सचथाय दैव्य इन्द्राय विष्णुः सुकृते सुकृत्तरः |
> वेधा अजिन्वत् त्रिषधस्थ आर्यमृतस्य भागे यजमानमाभजत् ||
>
> Even he the Heavenly One who came for fellowship, Viṣṇu to Indra,
> godly to the godlier, Who Maker, throned in three worlds, helps the
> Āryan man, and gives the worshipper his share of Holy Law.

Griffiths's translation is little ambiguous for me, and some people (may be biased) say that this verse says Indra serves Vishnu.

A word to word translation along with Sayana's commentatory would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RV 1.156.5:

> आ यो विवाय सचथाय दैव्य इन्द्राय विष्णुः सुकृते सुकृत्तरः ।
> वेधा अजिन्वत् त्रिषधस्थ आर्यमृतस्य भागे यजमानमाभजत् ॥

Sayana's commentary:

> ’यः’ ’विष्णुः’ ’दैव्यः’ दिवि भवः ’सुकृत्तरः’ शोभनफलप्रदानां मध्ये श्रेष्ठः ’आ’ ’विवाय’ आगच्छति । किमर्थम् । ’सचथाय’ सचनाय यागसहायकरणाय । कस्मै । इन्द्राय । आगत्य च ’वेधाः’ अभिमतफलविधाता ’त्रिषधस्थ’ त्रिसङ्ख्योपेतसहस्थानवान् सवनत्रयस्थानः क्षित्यादिस्थानत्रयो वा विष्णुः । ’आर्यम्’ आगन्तव्यं यजमानं ’अजिन्वत्’ जिन्वति प्रीणयति । ’ऋतस्य’ यज्ञस्य ’भागे’ हुतशेषरूपे तं ’यजमानं’ ’आभजत्’ भजति समीपयतीत्यर्थः । यद्वा । ऋतस्य यज्ञस्य भागे फले यजमानमाभजत् स्वामित्वेन स्थापयति ।

> He, Vishnu, the Divine, the most benevolent, the creator, who is manifest at three places (i.e. either in the three worlds, or in the three savanas), comes to help the worshiper (yajamana) in the yajna for the benevolent Indra. He (Vishnu) impels or energizes the yajamana to be the owner of the yajna (or) he makes the yajamana happy by giving him the good results of the yajna.

It literally made me sick with disgust reading Griffith's translation, which does not make any sense, and is couched in Christian terminology. It just hurts me deeply to see that our sacred Vedas are tarnished this way, and thousands of Indians rely on such translations in complete naivete and ignorance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So it only says Vishnu gives result of Yajna to Yajamana. It really does not say that Indra serves Vishnu/ depicts Vishnu supreme to or otherwise helping Indra from higher position .Am I right?

Comment: @Satya yes, that's correct.